# How to globally style all PrimeFaces input components having set required="true"

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

As an example, think about the following simple form with primefaces input components some of which are required:

```
<h:form id="person">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <p:outputLabel for="inputFN" value="First Name"
            indicateRequired="auto" />
        <p:inputText id="inputFN" required="true"
            placeholder="First Name right here please." />

        <p:outputLabel for="inputLN" value="Last Name"
            indicateRequired="auto" />
        <p:inputText id="inputLN" required="true"
            placeholder="Last Name right here please." />

        <p:outputLabel for="inputBD" value="Date of Birht"
            indicateRequired="auto" />
        <p:calendar id="inputBD" required="false"
            placeholder="Please kindly let us know the very starting point in time of your existence!" />

        <p:outputLabel for="inputFC" value="Favourite Color"
            indicateRequired="auto" />
        <p:inputText id="inputFC" required="false"
            placeholder="What is your favourite colour?? Green? Yellow? Please!" />

        <p:outputLabel for="inputFH" value="Favourite Hobby"
            indicateRequired="auto" />
        <p:autoComplete id="inputFH" required="true"
            placeholder="Your favourite hobby? Stackoverflow I bet!" />

    </h:panelGrid>
    (*) these fields are vital! Don't even think about submission when empty!

</h:form>
```

The rendered output of `inputFN` (required), `inputFC` (**not** required) and `inputFH` (required) looks like this:

```
<input id="person:inputFN" name="person:inputFN" type="text" placeholder="First Name ..." aria-required="true"
    class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
    role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">

<input id="person:inputFC" name="person:inputFC" type="text" placeholder="What is your favourite colour?..."
    class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
    role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">

<input id="person:inputFH_input" name="person:inputFH_input" type="text"
    class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-error"
    autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your hobby? ..." value="" role="textbox"
    aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

I don't see a chance to have a CSS selector catching only the required fields. Note that not all required components get the `aria-required="true"` suggested to use by @Malloware. For example the `p:autocomplete` `inputFH` doesn't.

As we have plenty of input components distributed in views and (nested) composite components and the `required` attribute is sometimes determined dynamically plus I am lazy, I'd like to **not** touch each and every component and add a `styleClass="#{something.isRequired ? 'required' : ''}"` to it.

**Is there a clean way to globally enable client side distinction of required vs optional fields?**

What I finally want to achive is to highlight the placeholders (using the `::placeholder` CSS selector) of all required fields by color, as an addition to the `indicateRequired` kindly provided by `p:outputLabel`.

Comment: _"For example the p:autocomplete inputFH doesn't."_ Then 'fix' that... Renderers are easy to override/extend and submit a pull request for the change. PF very often accepts them. And like  @Melloware mentiones, 7.0RC3 might already have a fix

Comment: @Kukeltje as a work around I will override renderers where this is missing until we can migrate as 7.0 will fixe it. Was still good to ask because I somehow completely missed the `aria-required` until melloware mentioned it. I also seem to have been asking the wrong questions to search engines ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this CSS selector. Gauranteed to work for all PF input fields for PF 7.0or higher.

```css
input[aria-required="true"] {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: This would be a good starting point. Just tried it out and found not all PF comonents have the aria-required, e.g. the `p:autoComplete` :-(  Additionally it must be refreshed on each AJAX request which might toggle the `required` attribute of components, but this is possible adding the script to a global AJAX onsuccess listener.

Comment: Are you using PF 7.0.RC3?  I think that fixes the aria-required on all fields, can you verify and let me know?

Comment: Why would you want to add the class and not use `:input[aria-required="true"]` as a selector in CSS?

Comment: @Kukeltje That is why I was asking I am not CSS expert so wasn't sure if that CSS would evaluate correctly!

Comment: @Melloware I'll try it this noon (CET). You can add the css selector to your answer as the (probably better) alternative.

Comment: `aria-required` was added to `p:autocomplete` to PF 5.2 but still missing from e.g. `p:inputNumber` up to PF 6.2. For PF 7 I can verify this is fixed. Looks like you [committed the changes for issue 4047](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4047).

Comment: updated my answer!   Also yeah for 7.0 I did a ton of refactoring so aria-required is now consistent on all inputs.

Comment: For me it works without the colon before `input` only. `input[aria-required="true"] {...`

Comment: Will this work on any editable value holder? I guess it will. In that case you might want to add textarea, select etc.